# How to access a website's data from an android app

Tags: android, web-scraping

I want to login into this website from an android app: https://driverpracticaltest.dvsa.gov.uk/login . Whenever I try to do this, I'm getting 403 forbidden. Is there any way to get the information without getting an error? Any help would be appreciated.